# Is view_context no longer available in Rails 3 views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1

in a current Rails 3.0.9 app of mine I had a few .js.erb templates that were using view_context in them so I could call fields_for on it during a ajax request.  This was letting me build some nested attribute form fields via ajax.  But upon upgrading to Rails 3.1 I'm getting the follow error:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `view_context' for #<#:0x1057b9f70>):

Was this removed/deprecated recently?  Is there another way I can build nested fields_for inputs without having the parent FormBuilder handy?  It seems view_context is still available in the controller, but I was hoping to keep this markup generation in the View layer.

My .js.erb template looked like this

```
<% meal_item_fields = view_context.fields_for :meal_items, Meal.new.meal_items.new, :child_index => "new_meal_items" do |f|
               render :partial => 'meal_items/meal_item_fields', :locals => {:meal_item_form => f}
             end
%>

$("#meal-items").append("<%= escape_javascript(meal_item_fields) %>");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [api docs it is deprecated in >= 3](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Base/view_context). Source of 3.0.9 returned self for view_context. I think if you were to try without view_context it would just work.

```
<% meal_item_fields = fields_for :meal_items, Meal.new.meal_items.new, :child_index => "new_meal_items" do |f|
                   render :partial => 'meal_items/meal_item_fields', :locals => {:meal_item_form => f}
                 end %>
    $("#meal-items").append("<%= escape_javascript(meal_item_fields) %>");
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to add `helper_method :view_context` in your controller.